# how to call a function from parent-sibling to child component in react-hooks

Tags: reactjs, components

[image]

*Here I have a situation need best help to solve it, i need to solve this by using react-Hooks. I am a newbie and need help!!!!*

---

There's a **parent** component who has 2 child component (**child-1** and **child-2)**. child-2 has 2 grandchilds (**gdc-1** and **gdc-2**). Now, I want to pass an arrow function **from child-1 to gdc-2**. i basically want to pass a value through that function. how to do that?

Comment: Can you explain what that value is/does? If it's a global value that's being set and retrieved you can use context or some type of store. For example. I had a situation where the page headers had to be shown in the nav bar. I used a lib called Zustand , created a store and then had a useEffect on each child, grandchild that set the page name , saving me the time of passing the setPageTitle through so many components

Comment: I am basically making an calculator, have made 2 children in my calculator.js file; screen.js and keypad.js.
screen.js has 2 children; result.js and computation.js
now my buttons are in keypad.js and have created function there, that when i click on buttons it should display on my computation-screen.js

i have tried to apply contexts-api (provider and consumer) i looked into many blogs and may videos but i'm helpless

Comment: please help me with that

Comment: i am not able to get this work, and have many errors on display

Comment: Create a code sandbox and We can check it out

Answer (score 0):

define the function and state in **parent** and then pass it to **child 1** and to **gdc-2** via **child 2**

Answer (score 0):

You can use Context in react to pass a value or a function without sharing unnecessary props to the child components

https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_usecontext.asp